# SQL - Select where parameter A has multiple values and parameter B also has multiple values where A and B are both key and pair values

Tags: sql

I have a table where I have parameter A and parameter B. I have to search based on 2 parameters which has multiple values but search should be based on key value pair   and not all the values in the parameter A and B has to be searched.

Ex: serial_num `[A,B,C]` and part_num `[s1,s2,s3]` are the parameter and its values.

I need to search based on A and s1, A and s2 but not A and s3.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample input data along with the expected output.

Comment: Together with the sample data, please also provide the `create table` statement for the table in question [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)  ([edit] your question by clicking on the [edit] link below it, do **not** post code in comments)